# Django update_or_create() UnboundLocalError

Tags: django

I am trying to update or create an object as so:

```
    today = datetime.datetime.today()
    store = store
    total_sales += products_total

    bill, created = Model.objects.filter(date=today).update_or_create(
        store=store,
        defaults={
            # 'date': today,
            # 'store': store,
            'total_sales': total_sales,
        }
    )
```

I am getting the error `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'total_sales' referenced before assignment`.

An alternative way to achieve the above is to do:

```
try:
   bill = Model.objects.get(date=today, store=store)
   bill.total_sales += products_total
   bill.save()
except ObjectDoesNotExist:
   bill = Model(
      date=today,
      store=store,
      total_sales=products_total
   )
```

With this alternative way, `total_sales` is set to `products_total` when created. Next time around, it already exists so `+=` will work fine and this error won't occur. But the point of using `update_or_create()` is to write cleaner and shorter code. How can I use `update_or_create()` when I need to perform an action on a parameter - if it exists - or create one if it doesn't exist?

Comment: If you want to *increment* a variable, it must exist. You can't increment from nothing. No, variables aren't initialised automatically. You have to set it to `0` initialliy and then add any product totals to that.

Comment: I do not understand the concern. Update your question to explain in more detail what you're trying to do and what your concerns are with doing it the obvious and simple way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a solution using `update_or_create()` but doing it this way with `get_or_create()` worked:

Set default for `total_sales` in model:

```
# set default = 0
class Model(models.Model):
   ...
   total_sales = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Use `get_or_update()`:

```
bill, created = Model.objects.get_or_create(date=today, store=store)
bill.total_sales += products_total
bill.save()
```